# Use Tailwind with PrimeVue

Tags: html, css, vue.js, tailwind-css, primevue

When installing PrimeVue, component style does not work, but Tailwind does.

I install Tailwind, then Tailwind works well after I install Primevue when I use the button of Primevue.
component style does not work, but tailwind does. Can someone tell me how to fix this problem? I try to research and fix it based on the document, but still, I don't know how to fix this problem.

html:

```html
  <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline">
  Hello world!
  </h1>
  <div>
    <Button label="Primary" raised />
  </div>
```

css:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

main.js

```js
import './assets/main.css'

import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import './index.css'
import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config';
import 'primevue/resources/themes/aura-light-green/theme.css';
import Button from 'primevue/button';

const app = createApp(App);
app.component('Button', Button);
app.use(PrimeVue);
app.mount('#app')
```

tailwind.config.js

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: Read https://tailwind.primevue.org/overview closely.

Comment: Do you want to use PrimeVue with its built-in styles + Tailwind on top of that, _or_ do you want to style the appearance of PrimeVue components with Tailwind?

Comment: I want to use PrimeVue component and can apply style Tailwind to PrimeVue

Answer (score -1):

In styled mode, you need to configure CSS [layer](https://primevue.org/csslayer/#tailwind).

In unstyled mode, this is not required.

Comment: I want to use primevue and tailwind Which mode should I use